# C++ std::set_operations (set_difference, set_intersection etc.) on nominal data

Tags: c++, set, std, intersection, difference

Sets are classified as unordered unique data containers. Thus set operations should work with nominal data (e.g. colors). But somehow std::set_operations like set_difference and set_intersection with custom compare functions only work with ordinal data (ordered data like int). Any ideas?

```
auto comp = [](const int a, const int b) -> bool {
    return a == b; // not working
    return a != b; // not working
    return a < b;  // works as expected
}
```

Comment: Because the comparison function is expected to return true if the first argument is _less then_ the second, not if they are equal or un-equal? I don't understand. Are you asking _why_ algorithms like `set_intersection` need to work with ordered data type? Well, because `set_intersection` returns a _sorted_ list (I mean, the sorting is preserved), how would you expect it to work with unordered type?

Comment: `std::set` **is** ordered.

Comment: Also, equality is a stronger requirement than a strict weak ordering, and implementing those operations with unordered inputs is much less efficient.